# Why the JButton doesn't appear on the JFrame if I try to implement abstract action interface?

Tags: java, swing, interface, jframe, jbutton

I don't know why the `JButton` isn't showing up in the `JFrame`. I think the code is alright and this is driving me crazy. Please if anyone knows what's happening I would be grateful.

If I add a button like in the commented section of the code it works perfectly but it doesn't if I try to make it with the `AccionColor` class. Could be a problem of the route I used for the GIF image? I don't think so. If it was that the button would appear but with no image, wouldn't it?

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EventosMultiplesFuentes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MarcoAcciones marco1 = new MarcoAcciones();
        marco1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class MarcoAcciones extends JFrame { 
    
    public MarcoAcciones(){
        this.setVisible(true); //hay que poner el setVisible aqui o si no no se ven los botones no se por que
        this.setTitle("Multiples fuentes");
        this.setBounds(550,250,600,300);
        
        PanelFuentes capa = new PanelFuentes();
        add(capa);
    }
}

class PanelFuentes extends JPanel{

    public PanelFuentes(){
       AccionColor accionAmarillo = new AccionColor("Amarillo", new ImageIcon("C:/Users/VicLo/Desktop/twitch/bichote pequeño.png"), Color.YELLOW);
//       JButton botonAmarillo = new JButton("Amarillo");
//        JButton botonAzul = new JButton("Azul");
//        JButton botonRojo = new JButton("Rojo");
//        
//       add(botonAmarillo);
//        add(botonAzul);
//        add(botonRoj      

        add(new JButton(accionAmarillo));
    }
}

class AccionColor extends AbstractAction{
    
    public AccionColor(String nombre, Icon icono, Color color_boton){
        putValue(Action.NAME, nombre);
        putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, icono);
        putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Poner la lamina del color " + nombre);
        putValue("Color de fondo", color_boton);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Divide and conquer by testing each part of your code in isolation. For example, first, just see if you can create an ImageIcon and display it in a JOptionPane

Comment: The frame should be made visible AFTER all the components have been added to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `revalidate();` after `add(capa);` in the end of `MarcoAcciones()`.